# How to remediate PHP5 code to PHP7

Tags: php-7, php-5.3

I am migrating some PHP scripts and I am how to correct the following old PHP5 code and make it PHP7 compatible:

```
$rc =& new ReflectionClass($class); // newOperatorWithReference
function Cezpdf($paper='a4',$orientation='portrait'){} // oldClassConstructors
$GLOBALS['rss_parser'] =& new rss_parser(); // arrayValueByReference
$rc =& new ReflectionClass($class); // syntax unexpected 'new'
```

I appreciate any assistance you can provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use references - for the `new` examples you don't need them anyway (objects are always "passed by reference"), which is the case for all your examples. It looks like you have a lot of PHP4 syntax, where references still had to be used, but nowadays there are rarely situations where you want to use them / where they add benefit.

For the class constructors - just replace their name with __construct, so `class A { function A() {} }` becomes `class A { function __construct() {} }`.